# python: aggregate columns in pivot table with multiindex structure

Tags: pandas, pivot, multiple-columns, multi-index

if i have multi-index pivot table like this:

[image]

what would be the way to aggregate total 'sum' and 'count' for all dates?
I want to see additional column with totals for all rows in the table.

Thanks to @Nik03 for the idea. The methond of concat returns required data frame but with single index level. To add it to original dataframe, you have to create columns first and assign new dataframes to:

```
table_to_show = pd.concat([table_to_record.filter(like='sum').sum(1), table_to_record.filter(like='count').sum(1)], axis=1)
table_to_show.columns = ['sum', 'count']

table_to_record['total_sum']   = table_to_show['sum']
table_to_record['total_count'] = table_to_show['count']

column_1st = table_to_record.pop('total_sum')
column_2nd = table_to_record.pop('total_count')
  
table_to_record.insert(0, 'total_sum', column_1st)
table_to_record.insert(1,'total_count', column_2nd)
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code for your dataframe? `df.head(5).to_dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.filter(like='sum').sum(
    1), df.filter(like='mean').sum(1)], axis=1)
df1.columns = ['sum', 'mean']
```

Comment: much appreciate! Thanks !  small remark - do you know how to keep same multiindex structure, if i would like to concat df1 and df ?